# Does TensorFlow by default use all available GPUs in the machine?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, gpu, tensorflow

I have 3 GTX Titan GPUs in my machine. I run the example provided in Cifar10 with cifar10_train.py and got the following output:

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:60] cannot enable peer access from device ordinal 0 to device ordinal 1
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:60] cannot enable peer access from device ordinal 1 to device ordinal 0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:127] DMA: 0 1 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:137] 0:   Y N 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:137] 1:   N Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:694] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX TITAN, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:694] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:1) -> (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX TITAN, pci bus id: 0000:84:00.0)
```

It looks to me that TensorFlow is trying to initialize itself on two devices (gpu0 and gpu1).

My question is why it only does that on two devices and is there any way to prevent that? (I only want it to run as if there is a single GPU)

Comment: Found [Any way to force TF not to occupy whole resources? (regarding multi-gpu)](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!searchin/discuss/gpu/discuss/QmMqfikKxlU/BC5P4XrDEgAJ) leading to [CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES – Masking GPUs](http://acceleware.com/blog/cudavisibledevices-masking-gpus)

Comment: That really helps. But why would TensorFlow automatically initialize for all devices on the machine? Btw just make an answer I will accept.

Comment: TensorFlow is aimed at 'research to production'. It seems the default to use all computation power meets the expectation to get its job done asap. Great that can be tuned, actually. But you mentioned 3 GPUs, and only 2 show in you logs. Why that?

Comment: I just found out it is because the third GPU is not functioning (for some reason that I don't know yet), so I guess if it was, TensorFlow would just use it too.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

See: [Using GPUs](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu)

**Manual device placement**

If you would like a particular operation to run on a device of your choice instead of what's automatically selected for you, you can use with `tf.device` to create a device context such that all the operations within that context will have the same device assignment.

```py
# Creates a graph.
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
  a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
  b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
# Runs the op.
print(sess.run(c))
```

You will see that now a and b are assigned to `cpu:0`. Since a device was not explicitly specified for the `MatMul` operation, the TensorFlow runtime will choose one based on the operation and available devices (gpu:0 in this example) and automatically copy tensors between devices if required.

```py
Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 -> device: 0, name: Tesla K40c, pci bus
id: 0000:05:00.0
b: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
a: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
MatMul: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
[[ 22.  28.]
 [ 49.  64.]]
```

---

Earlier Answer 2.

See: [Using GPUs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/using_gpu/index.html)

**Using a single GPU on a multi-GPU system**

If you have more than one GPU in your system, the GPU with the lowest ID will be selected by default. If you would like to run on a different GPU, you will need to specify the preference explicitly:

```py
# Creates a graph.
with tf.device('/gpu:2'):
  a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
  b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
  c = tf.matmul(a, b)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
# Runs the op.
print sess.run(c)
```

---

Earlier Answer 1.

From [CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES – Masking GPUs](http://acceleware.com/blog/cudavisibledevices-masking-gpus)

> Does your CUDA application need to target a specific GPU? If you are
>   writing GPU enabled code, you would typically use a device query to
>   select the desired GPUs. However, a quick and easy solution for
>   testing is to use the environment variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES to
>   restrict the devices that your CUDA application sees. This can be
>   useful if you are attempting to share resources on a node or you want
>   your GPU enabled executable to target a specific GPU.
>
> Environment Variable Syntax
>
> Results
>
> CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 Only device 1 will be seen 
>   CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1 Devices 0 and 1 will be visible 
>   CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=”0,1” Same as above, quotation marks are optional
>   CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,2,3 Devices 0, 2, 3 will be visible; device 1
>   is masked
>
> CUDA will enumerate the visible devices starting at zero. In the last
>   case, devices 0, 2, 3 will appear as devices 0, 1, 2. If you change
>   the order of the string to “2,3,0”, devices 2,3,0 will be enumerated
>   as 0,1,2 respectively. If CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES is set to a device that
>   does not exist, all devices will be masked. You can specify a mix of
>   valid and invalid device numbers. All devices before the invalid value
>   will be enumerated, while all devices after the invalid value will be
>   masked.
>
> To determine the device ID for the available hardware in your system,
>   you can run NVIDIA’s deviceQuery executable included in the CUDA SDK.
>   Happy programming!
>
> Chris Mason

Comment: I did exactly the same. But then when I did ```nvidia-smi``` I saw equal amount of memory is used from all the gpu devices.

Comment: the linked-to tensorflow gpu info is old/broken;  instead (as of 2017/10) try: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu

Comment: @Michael Thanks. Updated answer.

Comment: @GuyCoder : I have a similar doubt about running a tensorflow-gpu code. Its using all gpu but why all the cores are not being used just like the mulitprocessing module ? Could you check it ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54402154/how-to-achieve-gpu-parallelism-using-tensor-flow