# Tensorflow using all GPUs and still slow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, word2vec

I wrote a program to calculate word_embeddings :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import math
with tf.device('/gpu:2'):
        embedding_size = 5
        vocab_size = len(vocab)
        embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape=[vocab_size,embedding_size],minval=-1.0,maxval=1.0))
        embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings,train_words_indices)
        softmax_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([vocab_size, embedding_size], stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)))
        logits = tf.matmul(embed,tf.transpose(softmax_weights))
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,labels=train_contexts_indices))
        minimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)


# In[5]:

config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True,allow_soft_placement=True)
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
tf.initialize_all_variables().run(session=sess)
e,s = sess.run([embed,softmax_weights])
epochs = 100000
for i in range(epochs):
    _,l = sess.run([minimizer,loss])
    if i%10000==0:
        print('loss : ',l)
sess.close()
```

I have following issues :
1. I want my program to use a particular GPU (here gpu:2), but it is using all 4 gpus on machine.
2. It is not fast, it is running at same speed as without gpu.

I am not sure what is the issue here.

**EDIT:** On suggestion in comments, I am adding the information about GPUS I got :

```
([u'/gpu:0', u'/gpu:1', u'/gpu:2', u'/gpu:3'])
```

Also, program printed following lines :
Device mapping:

```
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 -> device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:1 -> device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:2 -> device: 2, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:82:00.0
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:3 -> device: 3, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:83:00.0
```

One more strange thing : Program prints all operations it is doing and everywhere, it says gpu:2 only, but still using other gpus. For example, some of the lines printed by program are :

```
Adagrad/learning_rate: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:2
Variable_1/Adagrad: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:2
Variable_1/Adagrad/read: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:2
Variable_1/Adagrad/Assign: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:2
Variable/Adagrad: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
Variable/Adagrad/read: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
Variable/Adagrad/Assign: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
gradients/embedding_lookup_grad/ExpandDims: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:2
gradients/embedding_lookup_grad/strided_slice: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:2
gradients/embedding_lookup_grad/concat: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:2
```

Comment: the comments and links are really helpful, Masking gpus on the TF init http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34834714/does-tensorflow-by-default-use-all-available-gpus-in-the-machine

Comment: I have added the information in the question.

Comment: It looks like this is mostly an embedding lookup right now. Maybe there's just not enough work in the matmul to keep the GPU(s) busy and overcome data transfer times?

Comment: What is the size of your data/model? If it is too small in may not justify the use of GPUs. Even worse, your training will take more time because of data 'messages' between GPU and CPU. If it is not the case, I have no experience.